# Can I set retry delay on task level?

Tags: airflow

Would it be possible to set the retry_delay on task level?

I have "global" `retry_delay` under `default_args` as 5 mins.

That's ok for most of the tasks, but for one particular task I'd like to set the `retry_delay` to 20 mins, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely.

Check out the Params for the [BaseOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html)